# iFrame shows the text in only one line

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, mathjax

I am using CKeditor and mathjax plugin. As you can see in the picture the window
resizes in width. So when i write something big , it doesn't fit in the screen.

I would like to add a line when it reaches the end of the textbox.

[image]

Desired result would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. What's the expected result?

Comment: the iFrame is the line of bold characters, i want to add a new line to this when it reaches for example the 500px in width. (this is the original width of the textbox)

Comment: I don't know creditor's plugin but if you can modify the underlying MathJax configuration, then you could try to turn on automatic linebreaks.